# How to find the width of text rendered by the DOM?

Tags: jquery, html, text, width

I'm trying to find the width of text rendered by HTML. Here's a fiddle of the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/ebytzdmv/

Key line of code that doesn't work:

```
var textWidth = $("#text").width();
```

I don't know why this code doesn't give me a number with the width of that text. I need it in order to make sure that text my webpage will display is always the same width as a certain image, even though the text is dynamic (a timer) and can change.

Comment: divs are from display type "block" by default so they have the maximum width that fits inside the parent. you need to use an "inline" or "inline-block" display style.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you havnt added jquery on your page and you are trying to use jquery using $, Your code is throwing error that $ not defined..

```
Kindly add jquery in the head of your application.
```

Below is the working HTML with your code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#text {
  position: relative;
  color: #81a136;
  font-size: 50px;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   try{
        var textWidth = $("#text").width();
      }
      catch(e)
      {
        alert(e);
      }
        document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = textWidth
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="text">
  Hi, I have a width.
</div>

<div id="answer">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If this has helped please mark it as an answer. with little green tick icon.